# why when I don't use ConfigureHttps, TempData is null in asp.net core 2.1 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, tempdata

I've tested TempData for sending data between two controllers, for example, SampleController to HomeController but it didn't work without ConfigureHttps. But when I marked the checkbox, ConfigureHttps TempData is executed correctly.why?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Sample()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Sample2()
    {
        TempData["Name"] = "Ali";
        TempData["Family"] = "Amiri";
        return RedirectToAction("Sample", "Home");
    }
}
```

---

This code is for  Sample's action in HomeController

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Sample";
}

<p>@TempData["Name"]</p>
<p>@TempData["Family"]</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem, and I fixed it.I've commented this code and then TempData is worked without ConfigureHttps correctly.

```
  services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>{
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```